# depstree.NamespaceNotFoundError: Namespace [name here changes every build] never provided

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library, kbuild

I am trying to build a really nice MIT licensed html5 billiards game.

http://www.agent8ball.com

Which is reliant on kbuild: github.com/kevmoo/kbuild

To build this google closure app.

Kbuild is reliant on brew, and I am on linux so I am using 
https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew

Every time I build I get a different namespace dependency error.
How do I solve these?

Notice it is not always the same error.
I don't think I've seen this in my programming career.

```
james@agape ~/projects/agent8ball $ ll
total 72
drwxr-xr-x 10 james james 4096 Oct 22 02:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 james james 4096 Oct 22 01:41 ../
drwxr-xr-x  6 james james 4096 Oct 22 01:30 app/
drwxr-xr-x  3 james james 4096 Oct 22 02:15 compiled/
drwxr-xr-x  4 james james 4096 Oct 22 01:30 config/
-rw-r--r--  1 james james  549 Oct 22 01:30 config.kb
-rw-r--r--  1 james james  165 Oct 22 01:30 config.ru
-rw-r--r--  1 james james  190 Oct 22 01:30 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--  1 james james 2425 Oct 22 01:30 Gemfile.lock
drwxr-xr-x  8 james james 4096 Oct 22 01:30 .git/
-rw-r--r--  1 james james   71 Oct 22 01:30 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 james james  234 Oct 22 01:30 .gitmodules
drwxr-xr-x  3 james james 4096 Oct 22 01:30 lib/
drwxr-xr-x  7 james james 4096 Oct 22 01:30 public/
-rw-r--r--  1 james james  275 Oct 22 01:30 Rakefile
-rw-r--r--  1 james james 1297 Oct 22 01:30 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  2 james james 4096 Oct 22 01:30 script/
drwxr-xr-x  3 james james 4096 Oct 22 01:30 vendor/
james@agape ~/projects/agent8ball $ ../kbuild/bin/kbuild build
kbuild: make_deps
kbuild: compile
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Scanning paths...
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: 873 sources scanned.
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Building dependency tree..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 256, in 
    main()
  File "public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 203, in main
    tree = depstree.DepsTree(sources)
  File "/home/james/projects/agent8ball/public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/depstree.py", line 56, in __init__
    raise NamespaceNotFoundError(require, source)
depstree.NamespaceNotFoundError: Namespace "box2d.PolyDef" never provided. Required in Source public/javascripts/eightball/PoolTable.js


james@agape ~/projects/agent8ball $ ../kbuild/bin/kbuild build
kbuild: make_deps
kbuild: compile
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Scanning paths...
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: 873 sources scanned.
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Building dependency tree..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 256, in 
    main()
  File "public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 203, in main
    tree = depstree.DepsTree(sources)
  File "/home/james/projects/agent8ball/public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/depstree.py", line 56, in __init__
    raise NamespaceNotFoundError(require, source)
depstree.NamespaceNotFoundError: Namespace "box2d.PolyDef" never provided. Required in Source public/javascripts/eightball/PoolTable.js
james@agape ~/projects/agent8ball $ ../kbuild/bin/kbuild build
kbuild: make_deps
kbuild: compile
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Scanning paths...
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: 873 sources scanned.
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Building dependency tree..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 256, in 
    main()
  File "public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 203, in main
    tree = depstree.DepsTree(sources)
  File "/home/james/projects/agent8ball/public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/depstree.py", line 56, in __init__
    raise NamespaceNotFoundError(require, source)
depstree.NamespaceNotFoundError: Namespace "pl.KeyBinding" never provided. Required in Source public/javascripts/eightball/application.js


james@agape ~/projects/agent8ball $ ../kbuild/bin/kbuild build
kbuild: make_deps
kbuild: compile
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Scanning paths...
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: 873 sources scanned.
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Building dependency tree..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 256, in 
    main()
  File "public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 203, in main
    tree = depstree.DepsTree(sources)
  File "/home/james/projects/agent8ball/public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/depstree.py", line 56, in __init__
    raise NamespaceNotFoundError(require, source)
depstree.NamespaceNotFoundError: Namespace "pl.images" never provided. Required in Source public/javascripts/eightball/loader.js


james@agape ~/projects/agent8ball $ ../kbuild/bin/kbuild build
kbuild: make_deps
kbuild: compile
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Scanning paths...
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: 873 sources scanned.
public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Building dependency tree..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 256, in 
    main()
  File "public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 203, in main
    tree = depstree.DepsTree(sources)
  File "/home/james/projects/agent8ball/public/javascripts/closure/closure/bin/build/depstree.py", line 56, in __init__
    raise NamespaceNotFoundError(require, source)
depstree.NamespaceNotFoundError: Namespace "pl.images" never provided. Required in Source public/javascripts/eightball/loader.js
james@agape ~/projects/agent8ball $
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the "pl" folder in agent8ball/public/javascripts

Seems this is a separate repo - https://github.com/thinkpixellab/pl/tree/27d32c3b47cafb23ffef19ab246107db53a7f02a

Comment: Worked great, thank you! Exactly the problem! Any idea why it was giving different errors each run?